# node_save is not same as saving a node manually

Tags: 7

I've removed many terms from a vocabulary and now I see this error when I see a node referencing the deleted term(also the attachment):

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7693 of D:\xampp\htdocs\gij\includes\common.inc).
```

I know it is an issue( like [this](https://drupal.org/node/1874396)) which goes away if I edit and save the node manually but does not work out if I run this code from Drush:

```
$node = node_load($nid);

 if ($node !== FALSE) {
  print "Saving the $full_path\n";
  node_save($node);
  }
```

Why this difference?

Comment: Try calling `node_submit($node);` prior to calling `node_save()`

Comment: How did you delete the terms?

Comment: @MPD I deleted terms using Taxonomy Manager.

Comment: @Krister Andersson .. did not work that way

Answer (score 3):

Try one of this options:

Explicit field deletion:

```
$node = node_load($nid, NULL, FALSE); // Force to load
if (!empty($node->nid)) {
  $node->field_taxonomy_term = NULL; // Reset the field
  node_save($node);
}
```

Submit the node form programmatically:

```
$node = node_load($nid, NULL, FALSE); // Force to load
if (!empty($node->nid)) {
  $form_state['node'] = $node;
  $form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');
  drupal_form_submit($node->type . '_node_form', $form_state, $node);
}
```

Edit all nodes on bulk with views bulk operations:

1. Install https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations
2. Add a new view page of content (node) and set fields as display.
3. Add field "Bulk operations: Content"
4. Configure the fields: SELECTED BULK OPERATIONS: "Save content" (check)
5. Save the view and go to the views path.
6. Select all items and the "Save" operation and execute it!
7. Done!

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing there is loading a node then saving it with same values. When using the UI, I assume that the referenced taxonomy terms are not available to render hence your fields will have reset values which are valid. So upon saving, you end up with updated records on your node.

I would reset the values of these fields if the taxonomy terms do not exist after node_load. Then save.

I hope it helps.